# Get request after a put or a post shows previous data instead of modified data?

Tags: c#, json, web-services, httprequest, windows-phone-7.1

The problem is that I do a GET request in the constructor(I call upon the method so every time that you enter the page the data is newly get from the database) and it gets the data from the database in a proper way. But after I modify the data and go back to page the data is still unmodified. The data changes in the database so the modify works but the GET request seems to get old data that is no longer in the database. How is this happening and how can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

```
public void getUserData()
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient("http://localhost:8080/GigShare/webresources");
    var request = new RestRequest("/user/{username}", Method.GET);
    request.AddUrlSegment("username", "" + user.userName);

    client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
    {

        getYourCarpools();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(modifyName.Text);
        userget = (User) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(response.Content);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GET");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(userget.name);
        modifyName.Text = userget.Name;
        modifySurname.Text = userget.surName;
        modifyUsername.Text = userget.userName;
        modifyTown.Text = userget.town;
        modifyStreetName.Text = userget.streetName;
        modifyHomenumber.Text = userget.homeNumber;
        modifyProvince.Text = userget.province;
        modifyEmail.Text = userget.email;
        modifyCarBrand.Text = userget.car.brand;
        modifyFuelType.Text = userget.car.fuelType;
        modifySeats.Text = "" + userget.car.seats;
        modifyavarageConsumption.Text = "" + userget.car.averageConsumption;
        getCarData();

    });
}


private void btnModifyCreateAccount_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    User outputUser = dataFromUser();

    var client = new RestClient()
    {
        BaseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/GigShare/webresources",
        Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("" + user.userId, user.password)
    };
    var request = new RestRequest("/user/id/{id}", Method.PUT);
    request.AddUrlSegment("id", "" + user.userId);




    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

    request.AddBody(outputUser);
    client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
    {


        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
        {
           // getUserData();

           // NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/NewlyAdded.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("PUT");


        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("failmode");

        }


    });


}
```

Comment: Sounds like caching. Try with Fiddler and check the request and response headers.

Comment: I had a suspicion it had to do with caching. But how can I bypass this?

Comment: That entirely depends on how your client and server are configured, what frameworks you use to make the request and generate the response, and whether caching actually is the issue. Please capture the request and response headers and update your question with the frameworks you use.

Comment: I'm using a restclient which uses System.Net.WebRequest/HttpWebReqest under the hood for its requests, so it should be respecting 
HttpWebRequest.DefaultCachePolicy regarding caching. I'm using windows phone 7.1 for the frontend part and a glassfish webserver as backend.

Comment: [Use Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com).